# Detached objects in standalone Java SE Client: Netbeans uses autogenerated DTOs?

Tags: client-server, ejb, dto, auto-generate

I have a problem:

1. I am working at a Java EE project, the GUI is writting by other persons.
2. I cretaed the database
3. I wrote a Java SE application (with Netbeans 7.1) which contains the entities (I let Netbeans generate these from database and fitted them)
4. I wrote the testclasses, wrote the ejbs and tested them.
5. I than wrote a singleton webservice in which the other beans are injected.
6. I the webservice, I got the expected result: it's possible to get the list of all instances (rows in the database), get an instance of an instance by ID, update and save it: all CRUD operations are OK.
7. In the Client, a Java SE Application (with Netbeans 7.1), I added a "web service client" by specifying the WSDL URL (of the webservice created in 6).

All what I got are detached objects. Every object with its all fields (as strings) EXCEPT THE ID (Primary Key).
instead of an update, I got an insert (cause the edited object has no ID on the client).
Remove doesn't work at all.
Other operations (findAll, findById) are OK.
Do I have to use DTOs (Data Transfer Objects)? I read that these are not more needed as of ejb3.1

On the client, for a findAll operation, Netbeans does not accept to use the entities: it forces me to use the autogenerated "dtos", which have almost the same fileds (except thhe primary key or ID) as the entities but as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I don't know why but Netbeans has autogenarted DTOs without the primary keys, therefore not all CRUD were possible.
This took me a long time and caused lot of headache!

Meziane